# Как перехватывать траффик по кнопке назад?

Tags: php, javascript, cookie

Есть ЛП, с него юзер уходит на сайт товара. Когда юзер на сайте товара нажимает на кнопку "назад", он обратно попадает на ту же ЛП. Как отследить возврат пользователя и средиректить его на другой URL?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    // происходит когда человек жмет кнопку назад
    window.location = "https://www.test.ru/other/page"
});
```

[Более подробно в этом ответе.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Честно говоря такие трюки находятся просто за пределами добра и зла. Представьте себе что ваша бабушка зашла на такой сайт, жмёт кнопку назад и попадает на совершенно другую страницу. Это совсем не весело. Лучше так не делать.

Comment: Забыл добавить, что у меня нет доступа к сайту товара. Он уходит с моей ЛП и попадает на чужой сайт. На чужом сайте я не могу разместить скрипт и повесить действие на кнопку Назад.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот пару вариантов. 
Дабавьте к ссылки на кнопку назад, `GET` Параметр, а на страница проверяйтесь если ли такой параметр, если есть, редеректим. Если же вы для кнопки «назад» используете встроенный в браузер объект `history` То тогда перед тем как отправлять пользователя назад, на какой-то промежуточный файл сделайте запрос, передав параметры Типа «сейчас пользователь вернётся на эту страницу, сделай редирект», пусть тот файл записывает выше описанные данные в сессию, а когда бунт редирект вы эти данные удаляйте. Но вообще, проще конечно будет просто возвращать пользователя ссылкой назад, используя `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` добавив к нему параметры возврата.

Comment: Забыл добавить, что у меня нет доступа к сайту товара. Он уходит с моей ЛП и попадает на чужой сайт. На чужом сайте я не могу разместить скрипт и повесить действие на кнопку Назад.

Comment: Тогда вариант, это сохранить куку, Типа «пользователь здесь был» и каждый раз проверять, есть эта кука или нет.

Comment: Думал над этим вариантом и даже сделал. Но, при возвращении назад скрипт не исполняется. Ощущение, что страница не загружается, а берется из кеша.